# Parser in parser-ts not consuming the whole input

Tags: fp-ts, parser-ts

I'm using [parser-ts](https://gcanti.github.io/parser-ts/) to write a simple parser for a template language.
The problems with my current parser are:

1. <strike>f I provide it with an incomplete template like `Hello {{name}` it enters in an infinite loop and never ends parsing</strike>
2. If I provide a string that is longer than a text and a variable like `Hello {{name}}!` it only parses the first two elements (text and variable) but it does not continue until consuming the whole string (so it includes the `!`)
3. When it finds an incomplete identifier, it tries to parse with the text parser and it succeeds, so I get two text tokens rather than a parsing error.

```
 import * as P from 'parser-ts/Parser'
 import { run } from 'parser-ts/code-frame'
 import * as C from 'parser-ts/char'
 import * as S from 'parser-ts/string'
 import { Either, pipe } from '@std';
 type TemplateText = { _tag: 'text', value: string }
 type TemplateVariable = { _tag: 'variable', value: string }
 type Token = TemplateText | TemplateVariable
 type ParsedTemplate = Token[];
 
 function TemplateText(value: string): TemplateText {
     return { _tag: 'text', value }
 }
 function TemplateVariable(value: string): TemplateVariable {
     return { _tag: 'variable', value }
 }
 
 
 // === Parsers ===
 type TokenParser = P.Parser<string, Token>
 // A parser that returns an empty string when it reaches the end of the input.
 // required to keep the same type as the other parsers.
 const EofStr = pipe(
     P.eof<string>(),
     P.map(() => ''))
 const open = S.fold([S.string('{{'), S.spaces])
 const close = P.expected(S.fold([S.spaces, S.string('}}')]), 'closing variable tag: "}}"')
 const identifier = S.many1(C.alphanum)
 const templateIdentifier: TokenParser = pipe(
     identifier,
     P.between(open, close),
     P.map(TemplateVariable),
 )
 
 
 export const OpenOrEof = P.either(open, () => EofStr)
 export const anythingUntilOpenOrEOF = P.many1Till(P.item<string>(), P.lookAhead(OpenOrEof))
 
 const text: TokenParser = pipe(
     anythingUntilOpenOrEOF,
     P.map((value) => TemplateText(value.join(''))))
 // function parseTemplate(template: string): E.Either<ParseError, ParsedTemplate> {
 const TextOrVariable: TokenParser = pipe(
     templateIdentifier,
     P.alt(() => text),
 )
 
 const Template = pipe(
     P.many(TextOrVariable),
     P.apFirst(P.eof()),
 )
 /**
  * Given a template string, parse it into an array of tokens.
  * Templates look like this:
  * "Hello {{name}}! You are {{age}} years old."
  * @param template a template string to convert into an array of tokens or an error
  */
 export function parseTemplate(template: string): Either<string, ParsedTemplate> {
     return run((Template), template)
     // return S.run(template)(P.many(Template))
 }
```